# Angular Frequency of a charged particle moving in a Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the Differential Equation in Mathematica but it is giving me error. How to find it's solution in Mathematica or in general.

$$y'''=\frac{\omega^2E}{B}-\omega^2y'$$

The above equation is for the angular frequency of a charged particle moving inside a magnetic field.

Comment: Not really a question fit for physics.stackexchange, but it's a matter of plugging it directly: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5By%27%27%27%5Bt%5D+%3D%3D+%28%5C%5BOmega%5D%5E2+%5C%5BScriptCapitalE%5D%29%2FB+-+%5C%5BOmega%5D%5E2+y%27%5Bt%5D%2C+++y%5Bt%5D%2C+t%5D).

Comment: Thanks for the help, where can I learn Mathematica?

Comment: A couple of possible starting points are this online [introductory book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/?source=nav) and resources in [wolfram u](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/language/).

Comment: A good place to start may be the [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). :)

Comment: Do you have a pdf format of this book?  @secavara

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, but on the right hand side of the book website I shared, you can find a link to a notebook version of all the contents in the book, as well as a link to a cloud version, which shows the contents on the right and a notebook on the left, for you to experiment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, can I ask questions related to Electrodynamics from you @secavara, I am an undergraduate student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this question is perhaps better suited to the [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), I think this differential equation is simple enough to be able to solve such equations by hand *before* resorting to tools like Mathematica! The key thing that you need to notice in the above equation that makes it very simple to solve is that $y$ appears nowhere in the equation. As a result, you could do the simple substitution: $$y' = u.$$

Using this, the equation becomes: $$u'' + \omega^2 u = \omega^2 \frac{E}{B}.$$

Such an equation is known as a non-homogeneous second-order linear differential equation with constant coefficients, and there are many ways to solve it. You can learn about them [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousDE.aspx) and [here](https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-NonhomgenLinEqns_Stu.pdf).

The adjective "non-homogeneous" means that there is a non-zero term on the right hand size of the equation above which makes solving the equation a little non-trivial. However, there is a well known theorem that the general solution to such a non-homogeneous linear differential equation can be written as a sum of two terms, $u_p$ and $u_h$: $$u(t) = u_h(t) + u_p(t),$$ where $u_h$ is the general solution to the homogeneous part, i.e.: $$u_h'' + \omega^2 u_h = 0,$$

and $u_p$ is a "particular" solution, one that you may arrive at using guess-work, which "takes care" of the term in the RHS.

Now, from the form of the differential equation for $u_h$, it's clearly the harmonic oscillator equation and so the solution is clearly just: $$u_h = A \cos{\omega t} + B \sin{\omega t}.$$

However, what about $u_p$? You need to guess a function $u_p$ that satisfies $$u_p'' + \omega^2 u_p = \omega^2 \frac{E}{B},$$

and some inspection should tell you that if $u_p = \frac{E}{B}$, then the equation is trivially satisfied! (i.e., the solution $u_p = \text{constant}$ is a solution to the problem, though clearly not the most general one!)

The general solution is thus: $$u(t) = A \cos{\omega t} + B \sin{\omega t} + \frac{E}{B},$$

and to find $y(t)$ all you need to do is trivially integrate the above equation. The general solution is obtained by putting in initial conditions, which will fix the values of $A$ and $B$.